# Pyinstaller + Tkinter + Mac OS + TCL

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, pyinstaller

So I am trying to run compile into binary a very simple Python code using Tkinter. Here is the code for test1.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk

counter = 0
def counter_label(label):
  counter = 0
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="dark green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I then used `pyinstaller` to compile by running the following:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --windowed test1.py
```

This runs fine and generates 2 files as expected (Unix's version of .exe and app). When I click on app file, it crashes as it starts - I don't see anything. If I click on the other file (.exe) style - it opens a new terminal window and eventually I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/pip-install-MgS374/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/pip-install-MgS374/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/_MEIJX4TS8/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/_MEIJX4TS8/_tkinter.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/_MEIJX4TS8/Tcl: not a file
    /private/var/folders/0t/1b6bbpcj52xdthkg2d6g2sr40000gn/T/_MEIJX4TS8/Tcl: not a file
test1 returned -1
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

What can I do to fix this? I think its something to do with TCL installation on Mac OS's version of Python. I saw different potential solutions on the web, but unfortunately none of them worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug in pyinstaller.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1350